# Process builder Criteria impossible to review

Tags: process-builder

Can I actually see my criteria in the Process builder once I have entered them?
Example picture - how can I know what the fields are? Is there a way to display the whole field path? Am I missing it, or did SFDC miss it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover over a field, it will show you the whole path. You can also inspect element and look for a tag like:

```
<a class="wrapper" title="Opportunity.MyField__c" etc>
```

Comment: thanks. I guess I never hovered long enough. Not optimal for checking your criteria against a list!

Answer (score 3):

Hover over the field with your mouse (same area shown in screenshot).   It's an annoying step, but it works.

[image]